# extract "columns" from a deque of lists

Tags: list, list-comprehension

I have a long deque of lists of 4 elements.
How do I efficiently extract columns from it?
I am using a comprehension list now as follows:

S=[s[0] for s in sample_D]
   R=[s[2] for s in sample_D]

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example:

```
>>> sample_D = [(i, i+1, i+2, i+3) for i in range(0, 1000, 4)]
>>> sample_D
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), ..., (996, 997, 998, 999)]
```

The [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function is useful to transpose a matrix:

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

```
>>> list(zip(*sample_D))
[(0, 4, 8, ..., 988, 992, 996), (1, 5, ..., 993, 997), (2, 6, ..., 994, 998), (3, 7, ..., 995, 999)]
```

The list comprehension returns lists, while the zip method returns tuple, but the content is the same:

```
>>> def using_list_comp(sample, indices):
...     return tuple([t[i] for t in sample] for i in indices)

>>> def using_zip(sample, indices):
...     z = list(zip(*sample))
...     return tuple(z[i] for i in indices)


>>> assert using_list_comp(sample_D, [0, 1, 2, 3]) == tuple(list(t) for t in using_zip(sample_D, [0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

If you need only one column, then the list comprehension is faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: using_list_comp(sample_D,[0]))
6.561095703000319
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: using_zip(sample_D,[0]))
10.13769362000312
```

But if you need multiple columns, the zip method is faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: using_list_comp(sample_D,[0, 1, 2, 3]))
25.433326307000243
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: using_zip(sample_D,[0, 1, 2, 3]))
10.10265000200161
```